# How to use AWS Elastic Transcoder on a bucket full of videos?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda, aws-lambda, amazon-elastic-transcoder

So I have an S3 bucket full of over 200GB of different videos. It would be very time consuming to manually set up jobs to transcode all of these.

How can I use either the web UI or aws cli to transcode all videos in this bucket at 1080p, replicating the same output path in a different bucket?

I also want any new videos added to the original bucket to be transcoded automatically immediately after upload.

[I've seen some posts about Lambda functions](https://blog.axcess.io/2015/09/21/automating-transcoding-using-aws-service-elastic-transcoder-lambda-s3-notifications/), but I don't know anything about this.

Comment: For part 2, here's a sample github project to trigger Elastic Transcoder when a video is dropped in an S3 bucket: https://github.com/bitblit/LambdaTranscoderTrigger.

Answer (score 0):

A lambda function is just a temporary machine that runs some code.

The sample code in your link is what you are looking for as a solution. You can call your lambda function once for each item in the S3 bucket and kick off concurrent processing of the entire bucket.